# Jsoup: encode the tag not to remove tag

Tags: jsoup

```
String source = "<h1> ... </h1> <div> .... </div> <span>...</span>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(source);
Elements elements = doc.select("div");
for (Element element : elements) {
    element.replaceWith(new TextNode(element.toString(),""));
}
Whitelist whitelist = new Whitelist();
whitelist.addTags("a").addAttributes("a", "href", "name", "rel", "target");
whitelist.addTags("h1","h2","h3","h5","h6","strong","u","i","ul","li");
String clean = Jsoup.clean(doc.body().toString(), whitelist);
System.out.println(clean);
```

The output is

```
  <h1> ... </h1> &lt;div&gt; .... &lt;/div&gt; ...
```

I was expecting

```
<h1> ... </h1> &lt;div&gt; .... &lt;/div&gt; &lt;span&gt; .... &lt;/span&gt;
```

i.e encode all html tag as `&lt;` `&gt;` except that i have added to whitelist. I DONT WANT IT TO REMOVE TAG.

Shall i have to specify each and every tag that it should encode as `&lt;` `&gt;` or is there any other way?

What I am missing ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? The job of the HTML Cleaner is to remove tags you don't work (really, to keep only the tags you do want). Do you want to HTML escape everything?

Comment: if a user input html code i just want to show them as it is. so for this i will hv to escape html tags except few defined tags

Comment: OK - that's not what the jsoup HTML cleaner does. It removes tags you don't want to keep. It doesn't have a mixed mode of keep some / escape some. You could escape the input HTML, but that'll escape it all. Your current approach is probably the simplest, if you really don't want to just remove the unwanted tags.